# Android Studio can't find my device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

When i try to compile on Android Studio i got this message:

> USB device not found

My phone is a HTC one X with CyanogenMod 10.1.3-RC2

- i have HTC Sync Manager V2.1.77.0 installed but when i try to connect my HTC my computer didnt recognize my Phone
- The USB Debug is Check
- When i type adb devices i got no device.
- in device Manager on windows The Android USB Devices is recognize

  [image]
- I have already try to adb kill-server then adb start-server and a adb devices but this didn't work

someone have any advice ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: After you installed CM, you likely no longer had an HTC VID & PID, so the HTC driver would be of no use.  See Ryu's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution for this,

find the id of your device in the device manager

like USB\VID_XXXXPID_0CD6&REV_XXXX&MI_00

and add this to your android_winsub.inf ( sdk\extras\google\usb_driver )

like this:

```
[Google.NTx86]

;YOUR PHONE NAME
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXXPID_XXXX&REV_XXXX&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&MI_00

[Google.NTamd64]

;YOUR PHONE NAME
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXXPID_XXXX&REV_XXXX&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&MI_00
```

And try to reinstall with right click update the driver.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Win8.1, but it did trigger a solution. First I got an error about 'possible corruption' of the .inf file. So I backed out the changes, and reinstalled anyway (by right-click on the .inf file). I then noticed an "Android Composite ADB Interface" item in device manager (don't think it had been there before). After that I ran Android Studio and started a debug session, and it detected my Nexus 7.

Comment: Device manager: right-click on `Computer` -> `manage` and in the window that appears `Device Manager` on the left. Right-click on the device and go to `properties`. In the new window go to `Details` and change the pull down menu to `Hardware Ids`. The two values need to be copied out.

Comment: For Linux users (and for the others too), it's better to follow https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_developer_options - that's the standard way of getting Android Studio recognize your CyanogenMod device.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem on a Samsung Galaxy. I uninstalled the device driver and re-installed it, it was able to detect. 
Another time, installing Samsung Kies software helped. You might want to find out the analogous for that.

Comment: didn't change anything, i'v just see another devices with the important sign (Yellow Triangle) in another devices with the name of HTC but i don't know how to install this, i've try with the 
'\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver' but he can't find the driver :/

Answer (score 0):

Although my computer could recognise my phone, I had to install the official drivers from the Samsung developer site to get adb/Android Studio to recognise it:

[Samsung Android USB Driver for Windows](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu with a HTC Desire C - Android Studio could not run apps on it (strange enough, all other phones worked "out-of-the-box").

To solve the problem, open (with `vim` or whatever you use)

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

and add your phone manufacturer. In my case, for HTC, I added this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

save&close and then run

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Of course you have to do it as root or `sudo`.

More info and a list of other phone manufacturers is listed on the android developer site:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html