# Device not visible to Android Studio after 5.02 Upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have just started teaching myself to make apps using android studio using my LG G2 phone which was running android 5.0.1 but I upgraded to 5.0.2 and it will no longer notice my phone as a debug target. It was working before, I have debugging mode on, I have developer options enabled, I have tried turning both my phone and computer and debugging mode on and off, and I have enabled tethering. I believe I need the 5.0.2 SDKs but I've been waiting since I accidentally updated my phone and I haven't seen them available. If all I have to do is wait, I'm okay with that but I'm not sure if that is what I need to do.

Would it be possible to downgrade back to 5.0.1?

[Response To paum_newbie]

I just wanna make sure I did everything you said right. My phone is a "LG G2" so I assume that is my phones name is LG G2. My hardware ids are USB\VID_1004&PID_633E&REV_0232 and USB\VID_1004&PID_633E Below I have the entire android_winsub.inf with my changes. Is this correct?

```
;
; Android WinUsb driver installation.
;
[Version]
Signature           = "$Windows NT$"
Class               = AndroidUsbDeviceClass
ClassGuid           = {3F966BD9-FA04-4ec5-991C-D326973B5128}
Provider            = %ProviderName%
DriverVer           = 08/28/2014,11.0.0000.00000
CatalogFile.NTx86   = androidwinusb86.cat
CatalogFile.NTamd64 = androidwinusba64.cat

[ClassInstall32]
Addreg = AndroidWinUsbClassReg

[AndroidWinUsbClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-1


[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName% = Google, NTx86, NTamd64


[Google.NTx86]

;LG G2
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_633E&REV_0232
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_633E

;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01

;Google Nexus S
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E21
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E23
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E24&MI_01

;Google Nexus 7
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E40
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E44&MI_01

;Google Nexus Q
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C10
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C11

;Google Nexus (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE0
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE4&MI_02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE7

;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01

;Project Tango (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D02&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D04&MI_02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D06&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D07


[Google.NTamd64]

;LG G2
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_633E&REV_0232
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_1004&PID_633E

;Google Nexus One
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01

;Google Nexus S
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E21
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E23
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E24&MI_01

;Google Nexus 7
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E40
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E42&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E44&MI_01

;Google Nexus Q
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C10
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_2C11

;Google Nexus (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE0
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE4&MI_02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE7

;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01

;Project Tango (generic)
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D02&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D04&MI_02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D06&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4D07


[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include     = winusb.inf
AddService  = WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUSB_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion  = 1.9

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg  = Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{F72FE0D4-CBCB-407d-8814-9ED673D0DD6B}"

[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg    = CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 1
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 1

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 2
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 2

[Strings]
ProviderName                = "Google, Inc."
SingleAdbInterface          = "Android ADB Interface"
CompositeAdbInterface       = "Android Composite ADB Interface"
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = "Android Bootloader Interface"
WinUSB_SvcDesc              = "Android USB Driver"
DISK_NAME                   = "Android WinUsb installation disk"
ClassName                   = "Android Device"
```

Comment: Is the problem that your phone's not on the list of devices? Try opening a terminal and typing "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server" then unplug and plug your phone back in. Then type "adb devices" and see if it's on the list. That fixes probably 99% of my adb issues. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: You do not need a new SDK, but it is possible for an upgrade to change the USB identity of a device to one not yet recognized by your SDK's ADB configuration.  On Windows, look in device manager, on Linux run `lsusb` with the device connected.  Or you may not actually have the device in USB debug mode - try disabling and re-enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen two different solutions that may help you. One of them is from an answer of stackoverflow which is:

> I found a solution for this,
>
> find the id of your device in the device manager
>
> like USB\VID_XXXXPID_0CD6&REV_XXXX&MI_00
>
> and add this to your android_winsub.inf ( sdk\extras\google\usb_driver )
>
> like this:

```
[Google.NTx86]

;YOUR PHONE NAME
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXXPID_XXXX&REV_XXXX&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&MI_00

[Google.NTamd64]

;YOUR PHONE NAME
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXXPID_XXXX&REV_XXXX&MI_00
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&MI_00
```

> And try to reinstall with right click update the driver.
>
> [Android Studio can't find my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987097/android-studio-cant-find-my-device)

And the one I used yesterday with my new phone, when my Android Studio couldn`t find it, which is: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Check my response to you